# What would be the path of my video using php

Tags: php, api, youtube

I am trying to upload to youtube using api.
I have a little problem setting the path to my video. I want to specify an url as a path for example:  `http://mywebsite.com/videos/myvideo.flv`

So here's what i did.

```
  $fileName = "myvideo.flv";    
  $fileType = "video/flv";   
  $newEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();  
  $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('http://mywebsite.com/videos/myvideo.flv');  
  $filesource->setContentType('video/flv');  
  $filesource->setSlug($fileName);   
  $newEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);  
  $newEntry->setVideoTitle("VIDEO TITLE");   
  $newEntry->setVideoDescription("VIDEO DESCRIPTION");   
  $newEntry->setVideoCategory("Comedy");   
  $newEntry->setVideoTags("VIDEO TAGS");
```

Now I'm getting this error message although i set the file permission 755:

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [flag] => 
        [msg] => File to be uploaded at http://mywebsite.com/videos/myvideo.flv does not exist or is not readable.
    )
```

)

Thanks Robby. Your trick worked. I just needed to specify the right path of my website host.

Comment: If it worked, please click the tick to mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying a URL, specify the full path to the file on your file system.

Also note that the YouTube API v2 has been officially deprecated by Google since March 2014. The PHP code samples for video upload in v3 can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads). Also in v3 you will need to specify a file path instead of a URL.